# simple bound for damped oscillation (trigonometric/algebraic inequality in one variable)

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

Would someone kindly recommend a method of proving this relation?
$$|e^{-2x}\sin(x)|\leq\frac{x}{1+x^2}, \qquad x\geq 0$$
Unfortunately differentiation leads to messy transcendental expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$|\sin x| \le x$, for $x \ge 0$ is well-known. On the other hand:

$$e^{2x} = 1 + 2x + \frac{(2x)^2}{2!} + \cdots = 1 + 2x + 2x^2 + \cdots \ge 1 + x^2$$

therefore $$e^{-2x} \le \frac1{1+x^2}$$

taking products, $$e^{-2x} |\sin x| \le \frac{x}{1+x^2}$$